# Can left recursion be eliminated in all cases in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

say I have the following

Grammar #1

```
expr:
    expr AND expr
    | expr OR expr
    | primary 
;
```

and is turned into this.

Grammar #2

```
expr:
    andExpr
    | primary
;
andExpr: orExpr AND orExpr;
orExpr: ... OR ...;
```

but I still don't see how this would solve the problem? In Grammar #1 I can express

```
true and false and true and true or false
true or false and true
```

I can keep chaining like this with Grammar #1. But I am not seeing how to achieve this using grammar #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
grammar Test;

parse
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : or_expr
 ;

or_expr
 : and_expr (OR and_expr)*
 ;

and_expr
 : primary (AND primary)*
 ;

primary
 : TRUE
 | FALSE
 | '(' expr ')'
 ;

TRUE  : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';
AND   : 'and';
OR    : 'or';

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

This will keep AND expressions have a higher precedence than OR expressions.

Parsing input like this: `true and ((false or true) and true or false)` results in the following parse tree:

[image]

Comment: Does the primary have expr in it? Can you please define primary also here so I see full picture?

Comment: Is primary: ‘true’ | ‘false’; ??

Comment: @user1870400 I edited my answer to include a working grammar.

Comment: What if there are no parenthesis? like `true and false or true and true or false` It would still work fine?

Comment: Yes, try it out.

Comment: Yes it works fine. sorry. I am trying to map this to my grammar which is slightly different and I get errors.

Comment: No problem @user1870400.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here is my actual question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60186343/how-to-write-antlr-rules-in-a-non-recursive-way I should have asked this in the first place? I am not able to identify where I am going wrong?